# Connecting Between Multiple IP Address in TCP

Tags: http, tcp, connection, ip

when i ask from DNS Server about somewhere.com it resolve 4 IP for me in this order:
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
and my question is what happen if first IP(192.168.1.1) doesn't work?
which service or protocol switch to next IP?
and what about other services like telnet,... (`telnet somewhere.com 443`)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, when the lookup is made, the returned list is not in any kind of order, it is somewhat random. This helps ensure one system is not overloaded.

What happens if the first address in list fails, will depend on how well the application is written.

What is *supposed* to happen, is that if the first IP address fails, then the application *should* then try the next and iterate though the list until the list is exhausted or a connection is made. You can see this with many pieces of software. However, many developers are lazy, and only try the first returned. I can think of quite a few applications where this happens.

It's not fun when you see applications request ANY expecting an IPv4 address and the returned list contains an IPv6 address, only for the software to barf.

Comment: thank you about your answer but i think that OS hanle this like tcp retransmition interval,...

Comment: You are wrong. The OS does NOT iterate through the IP address list, this IS left to the application. Go look at some network code and you will see this, specifically the bind call in C and what is contained within its structures.